# Use user location as a determinant in displaying content

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, location

I ask for user location and then extract their location so I can display it. This is how I extract  their location:

```
          func extractLocation(){
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self.userLocation) { (res, err) in
        guard let safeData = res else {return}
        
        var address = ""
        
     //   address += safeData.first?.name ?? ""
     //   address += ", "
        address += safeData.first?.locality ?? ""
        
        
        self.userAddress = address
    //    print(address)
    }
}
```

To display it, I just use `@StateObject` to refer to the `class` and then `Text(LocationModel.userAddress)`

In the app Im currently working, I want to display different content according to the location the users at. Information is stored in Cloud Firestore. As an example, lets have collection "FRIENDS". There, I have 3 auto ID:

1. name: Peter, location: New York
2. name: John, location: Los Angeles
3. name: James, location: Miami

So, if I'm in New York, only Peter's name will be displayed, if I'm in Los Angeles, only John's name will be displayed,  and so on.

I thought that using

```
db.collection("FRIENDS").whereField("location", isEqualTo: LocationModel.userAddress).getDocuments ...
```

would work, but the app crashed. How would I solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

this the exact code im using:

```
   struct Test: Identifiable{

    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
   var name: String

  }


 class UseLocationViewModel: NSObject,ObservableObject{

   @StateObject var LocationModel = LocationViewModel()
   let db = Firestore.firestore()
   @Published var test = [Test]()


   func useLocation(){

     db.collection("FRIENDS").whereField("location", isEqualTo: LocationModel.userAddress).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {return }
    self.test = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Test in
       let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
        
        let name = data["Name"] as? String ?? ""
        
        return Test(name: name)
      }
    }

  }
  }
  struct AnyView: View{
    @StateObject var useLocationModel = UseLocationViewModel()
    var body: some View{
      VStack{
        ForEach(useLocationModel.test){ info in
            Text(info.name).foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
       }.onAppear(){
        useLocationModel.useLocation()
      }
 }
 }
```

**EDIT 2:** if I use `.whereField(LocationModel.userAddress, isEqualTo: "location" )` I get the following errors after launching:

> RED ERROR   Thread 1: "Invalid field path (). Paths must not be empty, begin with
> '.', end with '.', or contain '..'"
>
> PURPLE ERROR       Accessing StateObject's object without being installed
> on a View. This will create a new instance each time.

If I use it as in edit 1 (.whereField("location", isEqualTo: LocationModel.userAddress)) I only get purple error

Comment: What crash report do you get?

Comment: can you post a photo for the crash report?

Comment: Actually, its not crashing anymore. Im just getting this purple error : Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time. I'll update ij the question the code exactly how im using

Comment: This purple error is referred to "db.collection()..." line